# Workflow: Send e-mail to assigned on creation if value is zero in another field?

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow, task-assignment

Is it possible to create a workflow in SharePoint Designer with these specifications and how to do it?:

- Just after item creation send e-mail to assigned person.
- But only if the field 'Value' is different from 0.

Best regards
Morten

Answer (score 0):

Create a workflow and choose start workflow on item add.

In workflow add **Condition with if and action called send an Mail**

```
if value not equals to value
          Email these users
```

You double click and add lookup values for mentioning the assigned person